# denary/binary converter cannot convert binary

Tags: python, binary, decimal, converters

I have been attempting to create a binary to denary converter and vice versa. Though the denary to binary works fine, the binary to denary just spits out the same input as I put into it... My code looks like this:

```
a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
b = []
c = []


while a != 3:
    if a == 1:
        print("You have selected denary to binary.")
        b = int(input("Enter the denary number you want to convert into binary: "))
        if type(b) == int:
            print("Equivalent binary number: ", bin(b))
            a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
        elif type(b) != int:
            print("sorry, your input is not convertible to binary")
        else:
            a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
    elif a == 2:
        print("You have selected binary to denary.")
        c = int(input("Enter the binary number you want to convert to denary: "))
        if type(c) == int:
            cbin = bin(c)
            print("Equivalent denary number: ", int(cbin, 2))
            a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
        elif type(c) != int:
            print("sorry, your input is not convertible to denary")
        else:
            a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
    else:
        print("invalid input, please try again.")
        a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
```

My output looks like this:

Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit...**1**

You have selected denary to binary.
Enter the denary number you want to convert into binary: **25**

Equivalent binary number:  **0b11001**

Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit...**2**

You have selected binary to denary.
Enter the binary number you want to convert to denary: **11001**

Equivalent denary number:  **11001**

... any advice would be great, I'm using int(X, 2) to convert binary to denary, but as you can see it's just not working.

Comment: Here `int(input("Enter the binary number you want to convert to denary: "))` you're parsing the number as decimal. Use the `base` argument here when you call `int` to parse it as binary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
b = []
c = []


while a != 3:
    if a == 1:
        print("You have selected denary to binary.")
        b = int(input("Enter the denary number you want to convert into binary: "))
        if type(b) == int:
            print("Equivalent binary number: ", bin(b))
            a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
        elif type(b) != int:
            print("sorry, your input is not convertible to binary")
        else:
            a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
    elif a == 2:
        print("You have selected binary to denary.")
        c = int(input("Enter the binary number you want to convert to denary: "))
        if type(c) == int:
            cbin = str(c)
            print("Equivalent denary number: ", int(cbin, 2))
            a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
        elif type(c) != int:
            print("sorry, your input is not convertible to denary")
        else:
            a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
    else:
        print("invalid input, please try again.")
        a = int(input("Enter 1 for denary into binary, 2 for binary into denary, or 3 to quit..."))
```

This line was causing problem:

```
cbin = bin(c)
```

Change it to this:

```
cbin = str(c)
```

Your program is not handling any type of exception, such as, if user inputs: 112 for binary, then it will raise error. I would suggest you to add **exception handling** too.

Answer (score 1):

Here `int(input("Enter the binary number you want to convert to denary: "))` you're parsing the number as decimal. Pass 2 as the second argument to `int` here to parse it as binary.

```
n = int(input("Enter the binary number you want to convert to denary: "), 2)
print("Equivalent denary number:", n)
```

You don't need to convert the number to decimal when you print it: numbers are printed in decimal by default.

By the way, all your `type(c) == int` checks are redundant. You already converted the input to an int, so unless an exception was raised, `c` is definitely an int.